# Unfocus element without blur event being triggered or prevent focus all together

Tags: jquery, click, focus, blur

I have a couple of input elements that are behaving like drop down elements in a similar manner that the jquery date event ui works. This needs to stay this way because of the nature of the application. I've set the elements to non-editable. This will allow the app to build a pseudo dropdown menu under it with a list of options while preventing the user from manipulating it directly. Once one is clicked, the jQuery plugin assigns the value to that input.

The issue is that there a validation checker that is triggered `onblur` so it looks like the validator is prematurely validating, of course it's working fine. I would hate to rewrite the validator plugin.

Is there a way to prevent the focus or blur event from happening all together in that particular click event?

Here's a js fiddle with the challenge

http://jsfiddle.net/powerphillg5/YHgKQ/

and here's the code that's there because we have to have code on here when providing the link #law-abidingcitizen:

```
<input type="text" id="my_input" value="Click me." />
<script>
$('#my_input').blur(function(){
    alert("Prevent me without removing the blur() and function that caused me!");
});

$("#my_input").click(function(){
    $(this).after("<ul>\
                  <li data-value='value1' class='click_me'>Now, click me,</li>\
                  <li data-value='value1' class='click_me'>or me!</li>\
                   </uL>");

    $(".click_me").click(function(){
        $("#my_input").val($(this).data("value"));
        $(this).parent().remove();
        $("#my_input").after("<img src='http://harrisongreetingcards.net/images/1316_thank_you_for_your_time_note_card.png' />");
    })

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is just unbind the blur handler from that event, so add this after you've added the handler:

```
// Add this after the handlers you want to prevent are added
$('#my_input').unbind('blur');
```

Alternatively, depending where things are added if you can't unbind the handler -- because it's not been added yet -- you can add your own handler that prevent any other later added handlers going off:

```
// Add this before the handlers you want to prevent are added
$("#my_input").blur(function(event) {
   event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Note, that this might have an impact of the overall functionality because you've essentially prevented those events from happening (and something might be relying on them). So you may want to rebind functionality at some point and fake the event, or just call specific functions.

**Edit:** After reading your question again. The blur event is happening before the click event, so you can't just switch it off from inside the click event. So if you want the blur event to happen in other circumstances (when you tab out of the box for example) you'll need do something cleverer. In that case you want to write your own blur handler that decides what to do, or alternatively you might need to add some other handlers that deliberately force the blur event -- perhaps when a different field gets focus.

I don't know your application so it's difficult to know what you need, but hopefully that should help you get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea, ugly but can work.

1. Hold the original blur.
2. Change new blur listener to call original blur by setTimeout.
3. Before the timeout firing, cancel it if .click_me element is clicked. Otherwise, just let it go.

Code looks like

```
var blurTimeout = false;
var inputObject = $('#my_input');
var inputBlur = $._data(inputObject[0], 'events').blur[0].handler;
inputObject.off('blur').blur(function(e) {
    blurTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        inputBlur.apply(inputObject, e);//call original blur.
    }, 500);
});
```

and add cancel timeout in the click function.

```
$(".click_me").click(function(){
    clearTimeout(blurTimeout);
    ...
```

and fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clxy/YHgKQ/2/).

Still, I recommend that change the blur directly too.